# populating sub object using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a relationship from Orders --> ContentRequest --> Institution table. How can I populate `ContentRequest.Institution` while doing the database search?

This statement below will populate `Orders` and the `ContentRequest` model. This works fine.

```
List<Orders> orderList = db.Orders.Include("ContentRequest").ToList();
```

I would like to have the `Orders.ContentRequest.Institution` model also populated.

Comment: db.Orders.Include("ContentRequest").Include("ContentRequest.Institution").ToList();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this (using this overload of [Include](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.113).aspx) extension method):

```
var orderList = db.Orders.Include(o=>o.ContentRequest.Institution).ToList();
```

Or you can still use the [Include](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708(v=vs.110).aspx) method you show in your question this way:

```
var orderList = db.Orders.Include("ContentRequest.Institution").ToList();
```

But I prefer the first solution because is strongly typed and in case you change the name of some property or you have some typing error writing the property names, with the first solution you will get a compile error.

Comment: For the first form, you need `using System.Data.Entity;`

Comment: thanks @EricJ. Right now I was looking a reference for Include extension method

Comment: `System.Data.Objects`? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708(v=vs.110).aspx